# be aware of the end of a loop of threads in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I have to generate images in my NodeJS app, using [Pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres)

I do it in a loop. So, I have 2 options:

Option 1:

```
async function makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename) {
    axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
    await new Pageres({delay: 2, filename: filename})
        .src(url, ['1300x650'], {crop: true})
        .dest("public/images/" + operation.data.name + "/" + yearAndMonthFolder + "/" + meterId
        )
        .run();
}
```

And then call it:

```
for (let firstDay = monday; firstDay < lastDay; firstDay.add(7, "day")) {
    await makePngScreenshot(url, id, filename);
}
```

This method is ok, but is very slow, as it is generating the screenshots one by one.

Option 2:

The second method intent to generate the screenshots with concurrence:

```
function makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename) {
    axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
    (async () => { // Make screenshot
        await new Pageres({delay: 2, filename: filename})
            .src(url, ['1300x650'], {crop: true})
            .dest("public/images/" + operation.data.name + "/" + yearAndMonthFolder + "/" + meterId
            )
            .run();
    })();
}
```

And calling it:

```
for (let firstDay = monday; firstDay < lastDay; firstDay.add(7, "day")) {
        makePngScreenshot(url, id, filename);
    }
console.log("done")
```

This method is much faster, and I would like to use it, but I don't know how to print `done` after all screenshots has been generated, right now, it prints before generation.

How can be aware of the end of all threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this purpose. You'll need to return a Promise from makePngScreenShot, which is a minor modification, and also call makePngScreenShot from an async function.

This would look something like so:

```
async function makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename) {
    await axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
    return new Pageres({delay: 2, filename: filename})
        .src(url, ['1300x650'], {crop: true})
        .dest("public/images/" + operation.data.name + "/" + yearAndMonthFolder + "/" + meterId
        )
        .run();
}

async function makeScreenshots() {
    let promises = []; 
    for (let firstDay = monday; firstDay < lastDay; firstDay.add(7, "day")) {
        promises.push(makePngScreenshot(url, id, filename));
    }
    // Wait for all promises to resolve
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log("done")
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with the project!